# Vote count not correct

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, information-display, vote-count

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044333/blal-blal-blbla-closed) the vote total is -8, but the vote breakdown is 1/10, so it should be -9 (may have changed by now, still gathering downward momentum, it had the same discrepancy at -5).

**Edit:**  Looks like someone deleted it, so only the 10ks will get to see what I mean.

Comment: Currently +1/-15 = -13. BOOOO to whoever the +1 was.

Comment: Sounds like a pity upvoter. I'm with you, BOOO!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question (now deleted and locked because of six spam flags) is at total score of -13 while the "split view" shows +1/-15. So this isn't just a timing issue when receiving the vote counts, but one of the counts actually got corrupted somewhere.

Comment: I see this same behavior.

Comment: Just curious - Why did people flag the question as spam? If Lance (4,966 rep points) took the time to bring this up on meta, then he must've cared about the question.

Comment: @Jim G: Not necessarily; a bug's a bug whether or not the question exhibiting the behavior is valid.

Comment: I voted to close the question and downvoted it, but I hate bugs.

Comment: @Jim G: the question text, in its entirety, was "Bla blbl ablal bla blbl alallblbllallalal". that's why it was flagged as spam and deleted.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this behavior too. When I refresh the page, the vote total corrects itself. (In your scenario, that would show the -10. Well, whatever the current total score is.)

My hunch is that it was at -8 when you first got to the page, but between then and the point where you retrieved the up/down split, someone else voted -- changing the results.

Comment: I did a few refreshes, it reset the 'split vote' format back to normal, but when I reclicked on the vote count it was still off by one.  I tried that process a few times.  BUT of course since it was an active post, it still could be a race condition.

Comment: I'm thinking that you're probably right about a race condition -- I've not ever seen it be persistent. I've seen it happen, but every time I've refreshed the page afterward, I got the total I expected.

Comment: see sth's answer- if you have 10k rep you can see that the counts are still incorrect even though the question has been deleted, and deleted answers can't be voted on so that rules out a race condition.

Comment: @Kip; acknowledged. Trying to decide between leaving the answer or removing it.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible for vote counts to be slightly off due to race conditions with voting and denormalized counts. This is not *common*, but it can happen.

The daily tasks check for this and correct any they find, though.

Comment: Also note that we ignore deleted posts when fixing denormalized scores.

Comment: I can reproduce this by canceling a vote: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69036/vote-count-incorrect-with-reproduceble-steps