# The case of the mysterious disappearing upvote

Tags: bug, up-votes, vote-count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vote count not correct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35185/vote-count-not-correct)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144034/why-cant-i-call-orderby-in-a-class-that-extends-list/2144044#2144044) (currently) shows as having 3 votes.  However, if you click the score (and, for some strange reason, only if you have >1K rep), it says that it got 2 upvotes and no downvotes.

In addition, in my recent page, and in [Jon Skeet's tracker page](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?so=34397&sf=&su=&meta=&mode=today), it shows as having only two votes, and the total ΔRep for today shows as 50 when it's actually 60.

What happened?
Was one of the upvoters deleted?

Comment: Showing the vote split is only available after 1k rep. by-design.

Comment: @random: I realize that. Why is it by design?

Comment: That question doesn't offer an explanation.

Comment: Vote splits showing only after you've "been with the site" for a while. Or to not tax the servers with the call. Not sure. Ask the devs.

Comment: @random: OK, I will. **EDIT** : did.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37116/why-do-vote-counts-require-1-000-reputation-to-see

Answer (score -3, accepted):

See this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35185/vote-count-not-correct/35207#35207) about the error.

Comment: That's a comment.

Comment: No, it's an answer.