# Please reduce or eliminate the reputation required to see the upvote/downvote vote split

Tags: feature-request, voting, privileges, vote-count

Stack Overflow is the only site I have enough reputation to be allowed to see the upvote/downvote split.

I wish I could do this on all Stack Exchange sites.

Could you please reduce or eliminate the amount of reputation required for this privilege?

Comment: Does it really matter?  It's got to be the least exciting privilege you can get

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: Okay, but you'll have to come up with an alternative for rewarding people that hit 1K rep.  Too many t-shirts btw.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do vote-counts require 1,000 reputation to see?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37116/why-do-vote-counts-require-1-000-reputation-to-see)

Comment: @JonSeigel, not a duplicate, because this here is a *feature request,* whereas that one was just asking *why* things were that way, tagged *support.*

Comment: @random. One thing that comes to mind is that on low traffic site a good answer can easly stop at two upvote. IMHO, knowing that the displayed 2 is +2/-0 or +3/-1 can help. Since many feel that they don't have to explain the -1 (so no comment stating what is wrong), losing even the info that the -1 is there in my view isn't desiderable. A -1 on a total of 3 votes can easly indicate that there IS an hidden pitfall somewhere in the proposed solution.

Comment: Near duplicate: [Please enable low-rep users to easily breakout up and down votes on their own questions (and answers)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40480/147650)

Comment: I see no reason for the restriction to be there for one's own posts (we already know the +/-, so calculating isn't that hard), at the very least.

Answer (score 13):

That's just the rep amount you need to be able to see it easily.

IIRC, you can see the up/down-vote breakdown for any question by going to `/posts/question-id/timeline`.

For instance, you can see the breakdown for this question itself at [`https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/72743/timeline`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/72743/timeline).

(It's currently at +1/-1)

Comment: Which is even stranger - basically hide something you could know anyway? Why then?

Comment: Maybe this proposal should then be change to make both visibilities to sync up in terms of required reputation; one way or another.

Answer (score 4):

You can view vote totals with a simple [userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/3082/48457). No 1k rep is required and on sites where you have 1k, this does essentially nothing.

With that there's no requirement at all.

---

Anyway, I think **association bonus** is a good threshold for seeing vote split. Whoever has an assoc-bonus can edit community-wikis on a newly-joined site.

Comment: I'd rather not depend on a userscript that can break on a small change by Stack Exchange, but good to know that it's possible to request this info from the API, because that's another reason to get rid of the reputation requirement.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative option, that I suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272205/298374):

Make it a privilege to earn the view vote counts privilege on every site.

This could have a higher threshold than the normal view vote counts privilege, for example 7.5k. That means,  if a user reaches 7.5k on any site, then they can split votes on any site in the network.