# Split up- / downvotes on demand also on meta

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please reduce or eliminate the reputation required to see the upvote/downvote vote split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72743/please-reduce-or-eliminate-the-reputation-required-to-see-the-upvote-downvote-vot)

On the Stack Overflow site, when clicking on the vote score of a question or an answer, the score is split up in its up and downvotes' parts:

---

[image]

---

I think this would be quite useful also for meta...

Comment: Yes, this is available, but just like the main site, it [requires 1000 reputation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-vote-counts). If you think it should be lower for the Meta site, support [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97892/rep-for-view-vote-count-privelege-should-be-lower-on-meta).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Please reduce or eliminate the reputation required to see the upvote/downvote vote split](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72743/please-reduce-or-eliminate-the-reputation-required-to-see-the-upvote-downvote-vot), [Why do vote-counts require 1,000 reputation to see?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37116/why-do-vote-counts-require-1-000-reputation-to-see), [Rep for “view vote count” privelege should be lower (on meta)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97892/rep-for-view-vote-count-privelege-should-be-lower-on-meta)

Comment: Thanks Cody, I didn't know that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is available on all sites, but [it requires 1000 reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-vote-counts) on a site to use it.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that. I should get more involved :-)