# Why prevent people from seeing upvote/downvote count if they can find out using the data explorer or the API?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, api, vote-count

There are some sites that I don't yet have 1,000 rep on (including meta), which means I cannot see the upvote/downvote breakdown.

There were some posts that I was curious about, so I [pieced together my limited SQL skills](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/s/1677/get-vote-record) to find out. This data can be up to a month old, but if I understand correctly, [a similar thing could be done with the Stack Apps API](https://stackapps.com/q/557/7653) to query real-time data.

What's the point of preventing people from seeing something if they can find it out anyway?

Comment: [Related](http://stackapps.com/questions/557/votecounts-bookmarklet-to-display-up-down-votes-even-for-rep1k)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do vote-counts require 1,000 reputation to see?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37116/why-do-vote-counts-require-1-000-reputation-to-see)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Showing the vote count is [supposedly too expensive to do casually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69852/why-privilege-to-view-vote-counts/69854#69854).  (See also, [Jeff's answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes/1007#1007).)

It's true that you can use custom SQL queries to get the same information (for now), and presumably that would be even more expensive.
**But**, far fewer people are liable to attempt it.

Hypothetical analogy:

```
Operation       "Cost"  Typical Attempts  Total Cost
--------------  ------  ----------------  ----------
Click to show     $22       1000            $22,000
Run custom SQL   $333          1               $333

Total, hypothetical savings:  $21,667 !
```

Comment: Also SEDE doesn't run against the production database, it's completely unconnected. So they don't really care how expensive the queries you run on it are

Comment: @Michael:  What about the API?  Seems like that must run against the production DB.  [This bookmarklet](http://stackapps.com/q/557) runs on the API and gives vote-counts on questions that are only minutes old.

Comment: It is; I didn't see the part about the API

Answer (score 11):

Why bother with the API?

To quote [myself, previously on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72743/please-reduce-or-eliminate-the-reputation-required-to-see-the-upvote-downvote-vot/72751#72751):

> That's just the rep amount you need to be able to see it easily.
>
> IIRC, you can see the up/down-vote breakdown for any question just by going to `/posts/question-id/timeline`.
>
> For instance, you can see the breakdown for this question itself at [`https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/100482/timeline`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/100482/timeline).

Comment: +1 Nice tip. But requires a bit of arithmetic.

Answer (score 6):

It's very convenient to just click on the votes and see them.  Convenience is a big perk.