# Get rid of the "Established User" privilege

Tags: feature-request, privileges, vote-count, userscript

The [Established User](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) privilege which is gained at one thousand reputation has been around forever. We all know that it lets you see the vote count on posts.

But I propose we remove the 1k reputation restriction that is in place to access vote counts. Or at least make it to where that privilege doesn't appear on the [privileges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/).

Why? Because that restriction is completely, 100% useless as you have been able to view vote counts without having 1000 reputation for ages, with [this userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep). You don't even have to be signed in to view the vote counts.

Why have a useless privilege when you dont actually even need 1k rep?

Comment: Have you read [Why is it a privilege to view vote counts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69852/289905) or any of its linked posts?

Comment: Most people who use the site don't use userscripts... lots probably don't even know what they are. ***You*** using a script doesn't mean the privilege is useless.

Comment: A third party resource isn't the same thing as the company deciding to let everyone see view counts.

Comment: Also relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122803/is-my-chrome-extension-unethically-circumventing-se-privileges

Comment: But it's still not a feature that exists on the site, at least not until you reach 1K. Why hide the ability to see vote counts at 1K from users?

Answer (score 5):

Let's set aside the question of whether seeing the *current* vote count on a post is useless.  I, too, use a userscript to see this network-wide, so that particular privilege isn't gaining me much except the ability to somewhat awkwardly view vote counts on my phone (as you might guess, I rarely do this).

**This privilege still isn't useless, because it lets you do more than that: you can also see the vote *history***

I can, for example, open up the highest voted question on Meta.SE, open the timeline, and click "Show Vote Summaries," which shows me [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/277369/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries) telling me on which days that post got each of its thousands of upvotes...and, for whatever reason, 8 downvotes (I guess those were from the people who'd been scraping the profile data).