# Can the threshold to see vote counts on Meta be lowered?

Tags: discussion, reputation, meta, per-site-meta, vote-count

I did find [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97892/rep-for-view-vote-count-privilege-should-be-lower-on-meta), but it is from over ten years ago, so I'd like to revisit it

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69854/1081494) explains why there is a minimum requirement (tl;dr the query is expensive). That makes sense, especially on a big site like Stack Overflow.

But I think it would be nice to let anyone that can participate on Meta (5 rep) be able to see vote counts, given that voting is different on Meta (voting is used to express agreement/disagreement), so I think being able for low-rep users to see vote counts on Meta would be good. 1000 rep is pretty difficult for a normal user to archive. Even lowing it to, say, 100 or 200 would be nice.

Comment: This doesn't really add any additional arguments beyond those in the original request, [Rep for "view vote count" privilege should be lower (on meta)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97892/rep-for-view-vote-count-privilege-should-be-lower-on-meta). If you have additional arguments to add, it's better to post those as an answer there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get rid of the "Established User" privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356719/282094), which links to https://stackapps.com/q/3082/58236 or https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122803/282094 if you prefer.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog No, it does not. I don't have an additional argument. My point is that whether or not the SE servers can support it, and if so, if they would consider it has changed, given that ten years has passed.