# How Can I View All The Reputation Gained/Lost For One Specific Question

Tags: discussion, reputation, questions

If I would like to view all of the reputation I have gained or lost due to one specific question of my own, how can this be done?  Is it possible for someone with, say, 421 rep on the site in question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably parse https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation and filter out the entries from a specific question id.

Here's a rather crude way, assuming you have a shell in hand:

```
awk -vQ=123 '{if($2==Q){sub(/[\(\)]/,"");S+=$3}} END {print S}' rep.html
```

where `-vQ=123` specifies the question/answer ID and `rep.html` is a saved copy of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation

---

And for kicks, here's a hastily written script which parses `/reputation` and prints out total reputation by post:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re, sys, fileinput
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(int)
re_post = re.compile(r'^\s\d\s+(\d+)\s\((-?\d+)\)')

matches = (re_post.match(line) for line in fileinput.input())
values = ((m.group(1), int(m.group(2))) for m in matches if m)
for post, rep in values: data[post] += rep
for entry in data.iteritems(): print "%s\t%d" % entry
```

Usage:

```
[me@home]$ ./parse_SEreputation.py rep.html
128123  20
128100  30
112068  20
113376  10
....
```

Comment: +1:  Thanks for the suggestion.  This should be easy enough to do, but I have a question about the data I see on that page.  What's the first number signify?  It doesn't appear to be rep.  For example, for my rep page one of the rows is: " 3     92508 (-2)".  What's the "3" mean?

Comment: My guess would be they're flags which differentiates upvotes/downvotes/deletions etc.

Comment: After looking at the data again, I think you're exactly right.  Thanks again.

Comment: Those numbers are the vote types, @John. See [How do I audit my reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation/43005#43005), which also explains how capped values are shown.

Answer (score 2):

While your reputation does not yet allow you to see [the vote counts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user), the API [can be used](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100482/why-prevent-people-from-seeing-upvote-downvote-count-if-they-can-find-out-using) for that. On https://api.stackexchange.com you can [simply create queries by clicking some options](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=113621&filter=!3wg4GB8fKvZ3Ut_pK&site=meta.stackoverflow), to see a lot of information.

Like [a query for one of your own questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/questions/113621?order=desc&sort=activity&site=meta.stackoverflow&filter=!LP4hJGl9vuhXHt518MMBMS) could return:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "question_id": 113621,
      "score": 3,
      "title": "Add Ability To Search Comments Only",
      "up_vote_count": 4,
      "down_vote_count": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

However: this does not take any [reputation cap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) (or the minimal rep of 1) into account. So, once you're able to see the vote counts, then the above does not tell you much more. In the meantime, there's [a nice bookmarklet](https://stackapps.com/questions/557/votecounts-bookmarklet-to-display-up-down-votes-even-for-rep-less-than-1000).

As an example for the reputation cap, using [/posts/1732454](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/posts/1732454?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&filter=!)rLtHUbkGP75RUn(rNR.) for an [infamous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) shows a huge total score, but that's not related to what the user really earned:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "post_id": 1732454,
      "owner": {
        "user_id": 18936,
        "display_name": "bobince",
        "reputation": 160591
      },
      "score": 4432,
      "up_vote_count": 4459,
      "down_vote_count": 27
    }
  ]
}
```

To see the actual capped gain, one needs [/users/{ids}/reputation](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-on-users), but I think that cannot be limited to a specific post (no `sort` and `min`/`max` there either), so for some users this might need a lot of queries to get to see the total rep for a specific post.

In this case, knowing the answer was posted 2009-11-13, became Community Wiki on 2009-11-19, was accepted before that and has no later bounties, one [can limit on date a bit](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-on-users#pagesize=100&fromdate=2009-11-13&todate=2009-11-20&ids=18936&filter=!masKNw__El&site=stackoverflow):

```
{
  "total": 94,
  "page_size": 100,
  "page": 1,
  "items": [
    ...
    {
      ...
      "vote_type": "up_votes",
      "title": "RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags",
      "reputation_change": 962,
      "on_date": 1258664195
    },
    {
      ...
      "vote_type": "down_votes",
      "title": "RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags",
      "reputation_change": -10,
      "on_date": 1258657425
    },
    ...
    {
      ...
      "vote_type": "accepts",
      "title": "RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags",
      "reputation_change": 15,
      "on_date": 1258298578
    },
```

For yourself, the list on Meta is not too long yet, so see [/users/142865/reputation](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-on-users#pagesize=100&ids=142865&filter=!masKNw__El&site=meta.stackoverflow&run=true) (or [/me/reputation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-reputation#filter=default&site=meta.stackoverflow)). Even when authenticated, this does not list the downvotes you cast yourself, so is different from [the report at /reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation).

The list is a bit longer [for your SO account](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-on-users#pagesize=100&ids=241536&filter=!masKNw__El&site=stackoverflow&run=true) though...

Comment: The above might not be 100% correct for Bobince's answer: the reputation page [adds up to 969, 2 points more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133739/bounty-cannot-be-awarded-on-a-locked-answer#comment381003_133739).

Answer (score 1):

Once you have enough reputation, you can view the vote count specifics on questions / answers.

[image]

From there, it's basic math. If it were an answer, it would be 24*10 + -1*2. If it were a question, it would be 24*5 + -1*2.

Comment: You would have to take the reputation cap into account, though. That's where it gets complicated...

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn also if it becomes a CW post you need to know what the CW datetime is and when the votes came in

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Hm, something I hadn't considered.

Comment: +1:  This would suffice, if I had 1000 rep.  Which I don't, and may never.

Comment: @JohnDibling - You have [30k rep](http://stackoverflow.com/users/241536/john-dibling).  Or were you just noting that this isn't useful for low-rep users?

Comment: @KevinVermeer:  I only have 421 rep on meta.  I cannot view vote count breakdowns on meta.