# Remove reputation threshold to see the split between up&downvotes on meta

Tags: discussion, meta, vote-count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rep for “view vote count” privilege should be lower (on meta)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97892/rep-for-view-vote-count-privilege-should-be-lower-on-meta)

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37116/why-do-vote-counts-require-1-000-reputation-to-see) asked to remove the reputation threshold to see the split between up and down votes. The rationale given for the restriction seems a little random:

> We just thought it would be fun to give folks something at 1000 rep [...]

Admittedly, that feature is more of a curiosity than a super useful thing to have on most sites.

However on meta, where up and downvotes are supposed to show the popularity of a request / suggestion etc., it would make a lot of sense to either remove the threshold or at least to make it low enough so that most people would qualify, say 101. Especially since [it is already sort of available](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72751/179508).

This suggestion is a duplicate but I thought the extra argument was worth it.

Comment: @random I don't think it's a duplicate: I am specifically targetting meta, which the other question is not, and my argument is that because votes have a different meaning on meta, they should be treated differently. I would have appreciated some form of answer on that point.

Comment: That's a good point. Reopened

Comment: Not according to the [screenshot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/48802429/Photos/sc.png) @random :P

Comment: @random Still looks closed to me...

Comment: random reopened this question and then closed it as a duplicate of a different question, @Robotnik.

Comment: @Gaffi see above