# Up-Vote Anomaly

Tags: bug, voting, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vote count not correct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35185/vote-count-not-correct)

[An answer to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522343/2522374#2522374) shows 3 votes, but when I click on it it shows +4/-0. I have also [gained 40 rep from it](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?so=118145&sf=&su=&meta=&mode=today). Why does the user interface lie to me :'(

http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/6064/uv1.jpg

http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/8438/uv2.jpg

Comment: All things considered I think this is better than an upvote anemone.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35185/vote-count-not-correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, for unexplained reasons, vote counts become corrupted.

It's happened at least [twice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35185/vote-count-not-correct) [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37114/the-case-of-the-mysterious-disappearing-upvote-closed).