# What is this? I am amazed

Tags: discussion, bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vote count not correct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35185/vote-count-not-correct)

Referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450895/how-to-achieve-multi-threading-using-javascript-with-ie6/2450904#2450904), I am experiencing some kind of bug.

When ever i click the vote count (which is 6 at the moment), it shows +7 and -0. If i refresh the page again, it shows total count as 6. I am able to reproduce this again and again.

Is it possible that the poster (Daniel) has used some kinda hack??

Moreover, if you see the Daniel's reputation graph, he has on average earned 200 reputation each day. It seems to me that users like him are here just for earning reputation, because if you observe closely, he didn't know anything about web-workers. But when other users posted about web-workers, he just copied the links from them and changed his answer (earning more rep. points). Is this kind of behaviour supported or am i mistaken?

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35185/vote-count-not-correct

Comment: and what about the second part?

Comment: SOFU must be more strict, upvote +5, downvote -2

Comment: They already plan to change downvotes to a larger number, no idea when.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to your comments about how he answers questions, his level of knowledge isn't important, as long as he's giving good answers.

We're all here for the <s>koolaid</s>rep.

Comment: ...and a few good answers.

Comment: i came here for finding answers.. but helping others helped increasing my knowledge (not every question though, numerous duplicates and stupid questions). So, i started sticking around. But, i am not here for rep. and what the hell would anyone do with the reputation anyway!

Comment: @user, that's a secret we don't tell you until you get high rep.

Comment: @users: chicks dig guys with **big** amounts of rep.