# Total votes on an answer is showed as 0 instead of 2

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, voting

I was reading [this](https://superuser.com/questions/132813/implementing-a-smtp-server-on-a-personal-computer-windows) question a few minutes ago and I realized that there are 2 upvotes, 0 downvotes but total votes equal 0 whereas it should be 2+0=2. Is this a bug?

[image]

[image]

Comment: i've seen a couple of those recently, generally with 0 upvotes and 1 downvote.  maybe something's changed in the migration process and those are leftover pre-migration votes?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35185/vote-count-not-correct

Comment: Interestingly, the problem has vanished now.

Comment: The score as displayed is cached but when you click to get the vote break down it has to go and get the actual numbers. If you refresh the page you should see the correct value.

Comment: Refreshing did not work for the first few hours, but when I checked the answer after 4-5 hours, there was no problem.

Comment: @ChrisF: yeah, tried that, saw the same thing.  i didn't keep track of the posts i saw this on so i couldn't go back and re-check later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be pushed to the sites tonight.

Comment: Looks like my cache theory was wrong then.

Comment: I just saw this on a question with negative votes. The question showed -1, but the vote split was 0/-2. Here's the link, but the votes will probably have changed by the time you see it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47375/what-is-the-most-downvoted-post-on-stackoverflow Edit: already gone. Still want to check out this issue, though.