# Question shows 4 answers but there are 5

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, specific-question, answer-count

There are 5 answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414494/wrapping-one-line-divs-around-an-img-not-text/3414852) but it says 4.

Comment: Just wait. Takes its time till the numbers change.

Comment: Ok... I wasn't sure if this could be a bug or not. 
@Grace... thanks for the tagging the additional keywords!

Comment: [Likewise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565725/spliting-based-on-comma-and-then-space-in-javascript): [5 versus 6](http://i.imgur.com/x4wkl.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two of the answers were posted at 12:19:28, in the same second. This probably lead to a race condition when updating the answer count.

Since this [happens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35185/vote-count-not-correct/35207#35207) from time to time with all the the different counters, there are scripts in place that run daily to correct such invalid counts. Probably until tomorrow the count will be corrected.

Of course they could use transactions in the database to avoid such problems, but obviously this isn't done in Stack Overflow.

Comment: that is interesting. so this would not be considered a bug?

Comment: @Hristo: I certainly consider it a bug. And I find it disturbing that they don't even seem to try to keep their database consistent, but hack around it with scripts that try to guess what should have happened. But then again it doesn't really matter all that much for the site if some stuff get lost from time to time, as long as it doesn't happen too often.

Answer (score 0):

One of the answers is deleted, that's why (I believe the post count is denormalized, so that explains why it isn't immediately updated when a answer is deleted).

Comment: Hmmm... if it is deleted then why am I seeing it?

Comment: Actually there are 5 answers + 1 deleted. @Hristo probably the system cache was updated when the 5th answer is deleted, but before you see it the 6th answer was added.

Comment: interesting. so would this be a bug?