# Issue with a lost edit

Tags: support, edits

When editing an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557215/should-an-entity-ever-know-anything-about-its-dao/3557287#3557287), I got a notification that whilst editing, it had been edited by someone else.

The notification appeared as I clicked *Save* so as soon as the page had finished loading, I went to look in the edit history and could only see my own edits.

Either I got a spurious "this answer has been edited" message or someone's edits weren't recorded.

Comment: You got notified of your own edit... It happens sometimes. Today must be your lucky day... Go buy lotto tickets and take up sky diving.

Comment: The same thing can happen when [posting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57932/edge-case-when-submitting-an-answer-and-checking-for-new-answers)

Comment: In your edit, did you add the backticks in the 2nd paragraph?

Comment: @Jon no - The edit listed does amalgamate a couple of rapid edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to happen sometimes and I always assumed that it is your own edit that, in the moment of being saved, triggers the "post has been edited" warning.

But it's also completely possible that it is just some race condition, where one edit gets lost. Race conditions aren't avoided in [other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59771/question-shows-4-answers-but-there-are-5) [cases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35185/vote-count-not-correct), so they probably also aren't for edits.