# Conflicting tag-only edit hard-stops me from submitting drafted edit!

Tags: bug, status-deferred, tags, edits

Just now I was editing a question, fixing tags and body. Before I submitted my (2k) edit, someone else edited, changing some of the same tags as I. Well enough; my edit was more complete, so I'll just submit anyway, right?

**Wrong!**

I get a bizarre popup from the tags field saying something about a previous editor had changed the tags *and therefore I would need to refresh the page and try again*.

Which I did (before getting a screenshot, unfortunately), and, of course, [on reload the draft was completely erased](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240378/losing-unsaved-edit-on-refresh-from-conflicting-edit), forcing me to resort to [Lazarus Form Recovery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/lazarus-form-recovery/) to avoid retyping from scratch.

This is not good UX and should not be happening. A tag-only edit is not magic*: if conflicting, the new edit can be layered on top just like any other conflicting edit.

A further, even more irritating glitch is that the editor dialog will *also* **incorrectly** display error messages for the other fields if they are edited. For example, if I edit the title — *even if the other editor did not* — it will display an error that the title was already edited.

<sub>**Unless it is. But why?*</sub>

Comment: ctrl-a ctrl-x, refresh, ctrl-a ctrl-v is what I do...

Comment: @Won't: I have an addon (Lazarus) that does a better job at that part. That's not the main problem here. The problem is the tag-only edit somehow interfering with the usual submission override that normally allows the second edit to go through anyway.

Comment: We’ve reviewed this request are moving it to our backlog. I’ve updated the status to status-deferred.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is something I'm currently looking into fixing.  The *best* way to handle this would be to allow you to load a diff of the edit that was just saved against what you currently have, then let you decide how to proceed.

In implementation, it's a tad more complicated, but we do want to fix it. It's particularly annoying in review,  where most work on substantive edits.

Hope to get on it at the end of this month.

Comment: So, [status-planned], then?

Comment: @NathanTuggy Maybe _at the end of the month_ or just 6-8 weeks ;)

Comment: For context [I was concerned about this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285064/what-causes-you-to-abandon-an-edit) when we rolled out the Help & Improvement queue. We _mostly_ skirt around the issue there with short-lived locks, but that was with the idea that we'd eventually just make the process better.

Comment: End of May was... a while ago.

Comment: @Nathan [tag:status-planned] means, as far as I came to learn, that a developer is actively working on a fix. Though, would love to stand corrected by Tim. :)

Comment: Still working on the fix?

Comment: @Jan judging by the lack of any response, I would say a plain "no". We can try again in 6-8 years.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars How prescient! Almost seven years is a pretty close match, wouldn't you say?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround: open the post in a new tab, make any edit you care to, then re-submit the original edit. Since you were now the last editor, it will go through, and will effectively replace the temporary edit in revision history.