# 5 Answers whilst there are 6

Tags: bug, answers, answer-count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question shows 4 answers but there are 5.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59771/question-shows-4-answers-but-there-are-5)

[Spliting based on comma and then space in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565725/spliting-based-on-comma-and-then-space-in-javascript)

I guess because I (pimvdb) posted the same time (at exactly the same second) as Guffa, it says 5 answers whilst there are 6.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Since you added that tag I see it has been reported already, however it is a bug by design if I'm not wrong?

Comment: that should be fix IMHO, but I have no idea why it is by-design.